Curved BottomSheet Dialog
How to create a curved BottomSheet Dialog in android like the image here
I have tried adding shapes like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="25dp" android:topRightRadius="25dp" />
</shape>


<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/curvedContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>

But didnot get the expected result. Any help is appreciated.

The easiest way is to create a drawable resource with the desired curved shape (using Adobe Illustrator or Figma maybe), then set this drawable as the background of your BottomSheet's layout.

@JaxonM Any other ways? Can we create it using XML shapes ? If so, can you share the code? Thanks
